META Catalogue Match Rate 0% - Missing Content ID
My catalog is connected to an XML file that automatically feeds product data into Meta.
I have a Meta pixel on my website with the following events that I installed through a Custom HTML tag in GTM, and they are firing correctly:
"PageView"
"View content"
"Add to cart"
"Purchase"
BUT, Meta has warned that the "Content_ids" are missing, which are necessary to match with the XML/catalog content/product ID, for example: 01t2v00000CrI9gAAF.
In the tags I’ve installed, I don’t use the "Content_ids" field, so I tried to add it, but it’s not retrieving this value. On my site, content_ids = item_id. I created a variable and pulled it into the FB tag, but it doesn’t seem to work.
I’ve tried various ways to get this variable, but it’s not working, and I can’t pull those content IDs into FB.
I've tried to change the tag and add this variable but its not working.
<script>
  fbq('track', 'add_to_cart', {
    value: {{value}},
    currency: 'AUD'
content_ids: 'item_id'
  });
</script>


<script>
  fbq('track', 'add_to_cart', {
    value: {{value}},
    currency: 'AUD'
content_ids: ['item_id']
  });
</script>



<script>
  fbq('track', 'add_to_cart', {
    value: {{value}},
    currency: 'AUD'
content_ids: ['123']
  });
</script>


<script>
  fbq('track', 'add_to_cart', {
    value: {{value}},
    currency: 'AUD'
content_ids: {{item_id}}
  });
</script>



{{item_id}} should be the most possible right one. Can you confirm the {{item_id}} is the right product id with the product page? You should be able to check it in the Google Tag Manager preview mode.
